# Overriding Named Route Parameters edit and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some issues with Overriding Named Route Parameters when I edit or create a post I get an error `undefined method playerId for nil:NilClass`. It still re-directs to the `:id` instead of the :`playerId` params only with create and edit methods.

Below, `:playerId` should be 101, but the 6 is the `:id`, not sure why it's picking it up.

```
SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`playerId` = 6 LIMIT 1  [["playerId", "6"]]
```

**Routes**

```
resources :players, param: :playerId
```

**Controller**

```
        def show
          @player = Player.find_by(playerId: params[:playerId])
          @season = PlayerStat.where("playerId = ?", @player.playerId).joins(:matches).where('matches.gameType = ?', 0).where('matches.teamId = ?', @player.teamId).group('year(matches.matchDate) DESC')
        end

         def edit
          end

          def create
            @player = Player.new(player_params)

            respond_to do |format|
              if @player.save
                format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'PLayer was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player }
              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end

          def update
            @player = Player.find params[:playerId]
            respond_to do |format|
              if @player.update(player_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @player }
              else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end

          private
            def set_player
              @player = Player.find_by(playerId: params[:playerId])
            end

            def player_params
              params.require(:player).permit(:playerId, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :teamId, :jumper_no, :height, :weight, :image, team_attributes: [:teamId, :name], player_stats_attributes: [:playerId, :gameDate, :kicks, :marks])
            end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method playerId for nil:NilClass

The problem is `params[:layerId]` is **nil** upon a successful `create` or `update` because you **aren't passing** any `playerId` for the `redirect_to`. So `@player` is `nil` which resulted in that error. Changing your code to below should fix the error.

```
format.html { redirect_to player_path(@player.playerId), notice: 'PLayer was successfully created.' }
```

Same for `update` too.

Comment: Amazing yet again Pavan. Rails God.

Answer (score 0):

you can define full routes like this:

```
get '/player/:playerId' => 'players#show'
get '/player/:playerId/edit' => 'players#edit'
```